# Is it possible to get aws account id with only aws access key and secret key in command line (CLI)

Tags: command-line, aws, amazon-s3

Is it possible to get aws account id with only aws access key and secret key in command line (CLI)

I have access key and secret key with me. Is it possible to get the account id using those in command line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
~ $ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "Account": "123456789012", 
    "UserId": "AIDABCDEFGHJKL...", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/some.user"
}
```

It works for IAM Users, Cross-account IAM Roles, EC2 IAM Roles, etc.

Use together with `jq` to obtain just the account id:

```
~ $ aws sts get-caller-identity | jq -r .Account
123456789012
```

Comment: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid Getting this error :(

Comment: That's because you've got `$AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN` environment variable set for whatever reason. Run `unset AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` first and then retry.

Comment: Getting same error :|

Comment: i got the output.. but for the below command    **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AXXXXXXGA AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=NXXXXXXt aws sts get-caller-identity**  But y shd i specify the keys for all the aws commands.. is there any other way to do so

Comment: @Vandhana you can save the credentials to a config file: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html

Comment: Yes i have stored the credens in the config file. But how ll i specify to take that file for the command??

Comment: @Vandhana this a a while new problem / conversation. Your original question *"How to get account id from access/secret key?"* has been answered above. I suggest you accept it as resolved and open a new question to get help with aws credentials file. Hint: `aws --profile {whatever} sts ...` :)

Answer (score 2):

The [sts get-access-key-info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-access-key-info.html) command lets you get the AWS account ID even if you only know the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`.

```
$ aws sts get-access-key-info --access-key-id ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
{
    "Account": "123456789012"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost every AWS object includes the account id.  For example, my IAM user is arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/Andrew.Lorien, and the ID of one of my cloudformation stacks is arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:ACCOUNT_ID:stack/my-repository/12345678-90ab-cdef-1234-567890abcdef. 
So you can query anything you know you have, and extract the ID from that.  Here's a bash one-liner which gets the first IAM user (a string like arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/USER_NAME)
 and extracts the account ID.

```
aws iam list-users --query "Users[0].Arn" --output text | cut -d ":" -f 5
```

Comment: **An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the ListUsers operation: The security token included in the request is invalid** Getting this error

Comment: Hmm, you must not have permission to read IAM, even your own.  I have a better answer, but it's a completely different answer so I'll post it separately.